What is the best way to keep a dir entry for further inspection later in the program?
I am always a little confused when it comes to work with the file system. What's puzzling me now is "DirEntry". I understood that I get an iterator of Result<DirEntry> when running read_dir.
But what exactly is a DirEntry and are there other means to get it besides read_dir.
I have to inspect and partly compare some text files in different directories where the filenames follow a distinctive pattern.
By now I use read_dir and keep only those entries that follow the pattern. After collecting them all I start to do the comparisons, now and then interrupted to get some user input.
From my point of view in the meantime there can happen a lot until I need to get to the entry again. Therefore I would like to refresh the entry before using it again. I would expect to get a result again in this refreshing process. But I didn't find a way to do that.
Or is there a better way to accomplish the whole task?

just a guess. when the comparisons are ongoing and there happens a user interrupt, you can break the loop, reinitialize the DirEntry iterator and start the loop again.

A DirEntry is the rust version of a dirent, which is the metadata a directory stores about the files it "contains".   If you know what files you're interested in, you can just keep the path or file name (or fd) around, especially if what you're interested in is the contents of the file(s).

Well, working with files is often tricky as it is susceptible to race conditions and TOCTOU. You might consider file locking mechanisms, if supported on your OS, or just handle errors from the possible file operation as gracefully as possible.

The most useful aspects of a DirEntry are likely to be the path and metadata methods. You can reload the Metadata of a given path by using std::fs::metadata. So, to answer your question, simply store the path from the DirEntry:
let dir_entry = std::fs::read_dir(".").unwrap().next().unwrap().unwrap();
let path = dir_entry.path();
drop(dir_entry);

// TODO: get interrupted by input here

let metadata = std::fs::metadata(&path).unwrap();
let contents = std::fs::read(&path).unwrap();

These will return an error if the file was removed. If you need to handle new files being added, there is no substitute for using read_dir to iterate all the DirEntry's again.

Fine! I do not expect that I have to handle new files during the run. Therefore this solution is fully acceptable.
Just out of curiosity: As I concentrate on files "file_type" is no longer interesting and path contains file_name, doesn't it? Does "direntry" make anything easier than using path?

You can call file_name on path, too! DirEntry doesn't really make anything easier; it just makes it possible to discover files in a directory. Note: the file_name is constant for a  given path, so you can cache it.
